# The system cannot find the file specified - Compiling in SciTE

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90

I need to start using Fortran 90 again after a few years away from it, and so I opened up SciTE, which I've had on my computer for years, and wrote a simple "hello world" type program and got this message when I tried to compile it:

> g77 -x f77 -ffree-form -W -Wall "hi.f90" -o "hi.exe"
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I did a bit of Googling to try to solve the problem, but nothing I tried worked. I tried changing the environment variables and reinstalling SciTE and the compiler. I'm not too good with computers so I don't know what's left to try.

One thing that I think might be the problem is that my computer crashed last year, and most of the current files I have were salvaged from after it crashed but before I reinstalled Windows, so I'm not sure if that might have had an effect on the programs. I kept most of the program files, but I ended up having to reinstall most of the programs anyway.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Well not to sound snarky but, is there a file called `hi.f90` where you're calling the directory and do you have a file called `g77` in your path?

Comment: Not really sure what that means...how do I know where I'm calling the directory?

Comment: Oh whoops, in the directory where you're issuing the above command

Comment: I'm a little confused... You use `g77`, specify Fortran77 and free-form, and compile a Fortran 90/95 file? Did you try `gfortran "hi.f90" -o "hi.exe"`?

Comment: You can issue `echo %cd%` to determine your current working directory and then get a list of files using `dir`. Is `hi.f90` among those files? If yes, issue `g77` without any arguments. You should get a complaint about missing input files (but no "No such file or directory" or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file from hi.f90 to hi.for, just in case g77 is looking for hi.f90.for (since you DID specify f77).